# AdMob and WebView within the same activity not working (Android app)

Tags: java, android, webview, admob

I cant get admob to work within an activity who has a webview tag in the xml file, the banner ad appears only 25% of the time, when it doesnt appears i get this message in log : "Ad is not visible. Not refreshing Ad". Heres my code

XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
      android:orientation="vertical"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="fill_parent">

<WebView
    android:id="@+id/webview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_marginBottom="70dp"
     />

<LinearLayout
 android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:gravity="bottom"
android:layout_marginBottom="5dp" >

<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView android:id="@+id/adView"
                   android:layout_width="match_parent"
                   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                   ads:adSize="BANNER"
                   ads:adUnitId="MY_ID_UNIT"/>

     </LinearLayout>

  </RelativeLayout>
```

JAVA FILE

```
package com.example.quickfeed;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;



public class UltimasNoticias extends ActionBarActivity {

 ProgressDialog mProgress;

 private static final String TEST_DEVICE_ID = "MY_ID_UNIT";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_ultimas_noticias);
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    WebView myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);

    WebSettings webSettings = myWebView.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    mProgress = ProgressDialog.show(this, "Cargando", "Por favor espere un momento...");



 // The "loadAdOnCreate" and "testDevices" XML attributes no longer available.
    AdView adView = (AdView) this.findViewById(R.id.adView);
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
        .addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR)
        .addTestDevice(TEST_DEVICE_ID)
        .build();
    adView.loadAd(adRequest);


    myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        // load url
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
        }

        // when finish loading page
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            if(mProgress.isShowing()) {
                mProgress.dismiss();
            }
        }
    });
    // set url for webview to load
    myWebView.loadUrl("http://www.quickfeed.com.ar/app/ultimas.php");
}



@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.ultimas_noticias, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
WebView myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);

    WebSettings webSettings = myWebView.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    mProgress = ProgressDialog.show(this, "Cargando", "Por favor espere un momento...");


    myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        // load url
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
        }

        // when finish loading page
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            if(mProgress.isShowing()) {
                mProgress.dismiss();
            }
        }
    });
    // set url for webview to load
    myWebView.loadUrl("http://www.quickfeed.com.ar/app/ultimas.php");
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
}
```

heres the manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.quickfeed"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >



<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="21" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/CustomActionBarTheme" >



    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".UltimasNoticias"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_ultimas_noticias"
        android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="com.example.quickfeed.MainActivity" />
    </activity>


      <activity android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity"
              android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"/>
<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
           android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
</application>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>

</manifest>
```

THE LOGCAT:

12-02 07:36:47.476: I/ActivityManager(2370): START u0 {cmp=com.example.quickfeed/.UltimasNoticias} from pid 4004 on display 0
12-02 07:36:47.482: I/wm_task_moved(2370): [2,1,0]
12-02 07:36:47.484: I/am_create_activity(2370): [0,920230720,2,com.example.quickfeed/.UltimasNoticias,NULL,NULL,NULL,0]
12-02 07:36:47.492: I/am_pause_activity(2370): [0,630334866,com.example.quickfeed/.MainActivity]
12-02 07:36:47.507: E/NetlinkEvent(1640): NetlinkEvent::FindParam(): Parameter 'TIME_NS' not found
12-02 07:36:47.539: I/am_on_paused_called(4004): [0,com.example.quickfeed.MainActivity]
12-02 07:36:47.554: I/am_restart_activity(2370): [0,920230720,2,com.example.quickfeed/.UltimasNoticias]
12-02 07:36:47.572: W/AudioTrack(2370): AUDIO_OUTPUT_FLAG_FAST denied by client
12-02 07:36:48.053: W/Resources(4004): Preloaded drawable resource #0x1080093 (android:drawable/sym_def_app_icon) that varies with configuration!!
12-02 07:36:48.115: W/art(4004): Attempt to remove local handle scope entry from IRT, ignoring
12-02 07:36:48.503: W/GooglePlayServicesUtil(4004): Google Play services out of date.  Requires 6171000 but found 5053030
12-02 07:36:48.541: I/Ads(4004): Starting ad request.
12-02 07:36:48.578: I/Ads(4004): Please set theme of AdActivity to @android:style/Theme.Translucent to enable transparent background interstitial ad.
12-02 07:36:48.688: I/am_on_resume_called(4004): [0,com.example.quickfeed.UltimasNoticias]
12-02 07:36:48.758: I/Choreographer(4004): Skipped 31 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
12-02 07:36:49.069: W/GooglePlayServicesUtil(4004): Google Play services out of date.  Requires 6171000 but found 5053030
12-02 07:36:49.160: E/GooglePlayServicesUtil(4004): GooglePlayServices not available due to error 2
12-02 07:36:50.475: I/Choreographer(4004): Skipped 163 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
12-02 07:36:51.499: I/art(2805): Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 7040(932KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 485% free, 1963KB/6MB, paused 5.136ms total 198.503ms
12-02 07:36:52.883: W/art(4004): Attempt to remove local handle scope entry from IRT, ignoring
12-02 07:36:53.480: I/Choreographer(4004): Skipped 270 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
12-02 07:36:53.708: I/Choreographer(2370): Skipped 106 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
12-02 07:36:53.770: I/am_activity_launch_time(2370): [0,920230720,com.example.quickfeed/.UltimasNoticias,6224,6224]
12-02 07:36:53.771: I/ActivityManager(2370): Displayed com.example.quickfeed/.UltimasNoticias: +6s224ms
12-02 07:36:54.223: I/Choreographer(2370): Skipped 43 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
12-02 07:36:54.908: I/Choreographer(2370): Skipped 63 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
12-02 07:36:54.939: I/Choreographer(4004): Skipped 133 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
12-02 07:36:55.482: I/sf_frame_dur(54): [com.example.quickfeed/com.example.quickfeed.MainActivity,0,0,0,1,0,0,1]
12-02 07:36:57.204: I/Choreographer(4004): Skipped 68 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
12-02 07:36:57.243: I/chromium(4004): [INFO:CONSOLE(0)] "Document was loaded from Application Cache with manifest https://googleads.g.doubleclick.net/mads/static/mad/sdk/native/sdk-core-v40.appcache", source: https://googleads.g.doubleclick.net/mads/static/mad/sdk/native/sdk-core-v40.html (0)
12-02 07:36:57.278: I/chromium(4004): [INFO:CONSOLE(0)] "Application Cache Checking event", source: https://googleads.g.doubleclick.net/mads/static/mad/sdk/native/sdk-core-v40.html (0)
12-02 07:36:57.279: I/chromium(4004): [INFO:CONSOLE(0)] "Application Cache Checking event", source: https://googleads.g.doubleclick.net/mads/static/mad/sdk/native/sdk-core-v40.html (0)
12-02 07:36:57.400: I/chromium(4004): [INFO:CONSOLE(0)] "Application Cache NoUpdate event", source: https://googleads.g.doubleclick.net/mads/static/mad/sdk/native/sdk-core-v40.html (0)
12-02 07:36:57.405: I/chromium(4004): [INFO:CONSOLE(0)] "Application Cache NoUpdate event", source: https://googleads.g.doubleclick.net/mads/static/mad/sdk/native/sdk-core-v40.html (0)
12-02 07:36:57.501: W/ActivityManager(2370): Launch timeout has expired, giving up wake lock!
12-02 07:37:00.037: W/Ads(4004): There was a problem getting an ad response. ErrorCode: 0
12-02 07:37:00.362: W/art(4004): Attempt to remove local handle scope entry from IRT, ignoring
12-02 07:37:00.472: W/Ads(4004): Failed to load ad: 0
12-02 07:37:00.474: I/Choreographer(4004): Skipped 30 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
12-02 07:37:05.557: E/NetlinkEvent(1640): NetlinkEvent::FindParam(): Parameter 'TIME_NS' not found
12-02 07:37:05.570: E/NetlinkEvent(1640): NetlinkEvent::FindParam(): Parameter 'TIME_NS' not found
12-02 07:37:07.948: I/art(4004): Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 20322(1273KB) AllocSpace objects, 6(96KB) LOS objects, 288% free, 5MB/9MB, paused 62.254ms total 611.250ms
12-02 07:37:17.266: E/NetlinkEvent(1640): NetlinkEvent::FindParam(): Parameter 'TIME_NS' not found
12-02 07:37:17.280: E/NetlinkEvent(1640): NetlinkEvent::FindParam(): Parameter 'TIME_NS' not found
12-02 07:37:21.021: I/Choreographer(4004): Skipped 38 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
12-02 07:37:21.402: I/Choreographer(4004): Skipped 36 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
12-02 07:37:22.265: I/Choreographer(4004): Skipped 30 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
12-02 07:37:22.299: I/netstats_mobile_sample(2370): [9036180,9261,552404,5716,8888646,9257,472268,5712,8741567,9158,471901,5689,1417523842185]
12-02 07:37:22.304: I/netstats_wifi_sample(2370): [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1417523842185]
12-02 07:37:22.754: I/Choreographer(4004): Skipped 45 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
12-02 07:37:23.079: I/Choreographer(4004): Skipped 30 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
12-02 07:37:23.418: I/Choreographer(4004): Skipped 32 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
12-02 07:37:23.750: I/Choreographer(4004): Skipped 31 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
12-02 07:37:25.048: I/Choreographer(4004): Skipped 36 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
12-02 07:37:25.950: I/Choreographer(4004): Skipped 31 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
12-02 07:37:40.975: D/LightsService(2370): Excessive delay setting light: 591ms
12-02 07:37:41.069: D/LightsService(2370): Excessive delay setting light: 94ms
12-02 07:37:42.948: I/Choreographer(4004): Skipped 149 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
12-02 07:37:44.627: I/free_storage_changed(2370): 110465024
12-02 07:37:45.174: I/auditd(3196): type=1400 audit(0.0:24): avc:  denied  { 0x10 } for  comm="Binder_A" capability=36  scontext=u:r:system_server:s0 tcontext=u:r:system_server:s0 tclass=capability2
12-02 07:37:45.339: I/Choreographer(4004): Skipped 97 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
12-02 07:37:46.001: I/sf_frame_dur(54): [Cargando,0,0,0,196,83,9,3]

Comment: please post the manifest file have u added permissiaon in manifest

Comment: yes i added permission, added the manifest to the question

Comment: post your logcat for when the ad is not displayed - the answer will be in there.

Comment: above is the logcat for when the ad is not shown, i now get an errorcode 0, but sometimes its just "ads is not visible"

Comment: any ideas?? cant see anything helpful in the logcat

Answer (score 0):

your activity layout is quite weird! remove the LinearLayout and work with the following tags within com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView android:id="@+id/adView"

```
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
```

Then try not loading a url in the webview. In this case, are ads shown a 100% of the time?

Comment: Yes, if i dont use a webview ads are shown 100% of the time, but with a webview tag ads are shown 25% of the time aprox. I tried removing the linear layout, but i get this error instead "there was a problem getting an ad response. Errorcode: 0"